# Feasibility of a given set of Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, quadratic-programming

This arises as a part of my work. Given a positive number $t$, two hermitian matrices $P_1$ and $P_2$, I am interested in knowing if a unit norm vector $z$ exists such that 
\begin{align}
z^{H}P_1z\geq t \\
z^{H}P_2z\geq t
\end{align}

**A possible reformulation**

The vector being unit norm, one can reformulate the above problem as to check whether a unit norm solution exists for 
\begin{align}
z^{H}(P_1-tI)z\geq 0 \\
z^{H}P_2-tI)z\geq 0
\end{align}
Note that $t$ is a given positive constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: expand $z$ in terms of the eigenvectors of $P_1$ or $P_2$, it's easy to show that the necessary condition is $\min(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) \ge t$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the largest eigenvalue of $P_1$ and $P_2$, respectively.

And if the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is also the eigenvector associated with $\lambda_2$, then this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: It is not a sufficient condition. If you take $P_1 = \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 }$ and $P_2 = -P_1$, then both the largest eigenvalues are $\geq 1$, but $z^*P_1 z = - z^* P_2 z$, so they can never be simultaneously greater than $0$.

Comment: @copper.hat But the OP asked for $z^HP_iz \ge 0, \text{not} z^HP_iz > 0 \; (i=1,2)$

Comment: The OP asked for $\geq t > 0$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat answer is edited.

Comment: @chaohuang thanks for the answer, but that doesn't help in general. In my case, I will be generating this matrices randomly, and the probability for the situation you mentioned happening is almost always zero.